# Why we say I need help not I need a help?

Tags: articles, nouns

I know that we must use articles before nouns. Sometimes we don't as in the following examples

> - I need help.
> - Help is coming.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your examples, “help” is used as an unspecified uncountable noun. Hence, we don't need to use the definite article. For example, "apple" is countable, whereas "meat" is uncountable (it would be correct to say "two apples", but not "two meats")